# How to resize a partition on a server without a display?

Tags: partitioning

I've recently run into an issue where I need to resize a partition on a server, but the issue is, it has no GUI so I cannot use gparted. What should I do in this case?

So I get it that you should use parted. However, how exactly do you use the parted command? What does it mean by start and end?

Comment: Use parted (gparted is a graphical front end). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/390769/resize-my-root-partion-in-ubuntu-server

Comment: That doesn't help much.. I get that parted is the answer, but what does it mean by start and end..?

Comment: You should update your question then , ask for clarification

Comment: Done, it should be more clear now.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer I've added a bounty to the other question, so someone will improve its answer. In the meantime I will reopen this. It'll probably be closed again as soon as a) you get an answer (then I'll merge the two) or b) the other question gets a in depth answer. Just a heads up :)

Comment: @Seth are you still going to merge them? What's the status on that? The answers on the other question are for 1)resizing the root partition, or 2)creating a swap space without partitioning. If VoidWhisperer wants to resize a non-root partition, those answers won't do him any good. I can post a step-by-step answer here on how to resize a non-root partition through the command line. My answer won't apply to the other question because that question is for resizing the root partition.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer are you looking to resize the root partition? Or another partition on the disk? Resize root partition = you have to use liveCD (mentioned in the answers on the other question). Resize another partition = I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: @AlaaAli (Sorry for the late reply). Hm, you're right. That is something I hadn't taken into account. I guess I will just leave them now.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`parted`**:

```
parted device resize minor start end
```

Resizes the partition with number *minor* from device *device*. The partition will start *start* from the beginning of the disk, and end *end* from the beginning of the disk. `resize` never changes the *minor* number. Extended partitions can be resized, so long as the new extended partition completely contains all logical partitions.

Note that `parted` does not require a file system to be "defragged" (`parted` can safely move data around if necessary).

Supported file systems:

- ext2, ext3 - restriction: the new start must be the same as the old start.
- fat16, fat32
- linux-swap
- reiserfs (if libreiserfs is installed)

**Example:**

```
sudo parted -i /dev/sda resize 3 200 850
```

Resize partition 3 from `/dev/sda`, so that it begins 200 megabytes and ends 850 megabytes from the beginning of the disk. `-i` (`--interactive`) prompt for your intervention, where necessary.

Source: [Parted User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html).

See also `man parted` for more info.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on how I would change the partition size with this.. Why isn't it just simple like giving it a new size to change it to?

Comment: @VoidWhisperer In the given example 850-200=650 is the new size :). Use `sudo parted /dev/sda print` command to find out the current start and the current end.